# How to create shared library with gcc in hp-ux?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, sas, hp-ux

I try to create a shared library with gcc compiler on hp-ux. I use these commands:

1. gcc -Wall -fPIC -std=gnu99 -c *.c
2. gcc -shared -Wl -o my_library.so *.o

Everything compiles without warnings or errors, but when I try to use that library, I get an error:

ERROR: Extension Load Failure: OS Error: -1 ('*path_to_lib*' is not a valid load module: Bad magic number).
ERROR: Unable to load extension: (*path_to_lib*).
ERROR: Extension Load Failure: OS Error: -1 ('*path_to_lib*' is not a valid load module: Bad magic number)

Do you know what does this error exactly mean? How to fix it?

**EDITED:**
I use my shared library in SAS program like this:

```
proc proto package =work.myfuncs.tests;
   link "/home/my_library.so";

   int test(int x);
run;
```

Comment: How do you *try to use that library* exactly?

Comment: I use it in SAS software. I don't know if it is worth to mention the usage details, because it is completely other technology, also everything works in LINUX environment. I thought, that I have to use some more compile-time arguments because of this error ' Bad magic number'.

Comment: If same things are working on Linux then surely it is linking issue on your SAS software. please verify if your lib is actually linked during the compilation,.

Comment: @Dayalrai could you please give more details how to do that?

Comment: Can *you* give us more detail on how you try to use the lib, how you link it, and so on?

Comment: I edited my question with usage details.

Comment: Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting correctly?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not used in `proc proto` function.

Comment: I THINK this is a problem with how your are using the `LINK` statement in `PROC PROTO.`  Can you paste the actual line of code here?

Comment: Actually I've already done that in a question, @DomPazz.

Comment: @polis, sorry about that.  You should send this to SAS Tech Support.  This is an error they can probably help you with better than us.

Comment: PROC PROTO packages are loaded in the order that is specified in the CMPLIB option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem. I had to create library as 64 bits library with gcc option `-mlp64`, because SAS software was 64 bits. However, I still don't know why `proc proto` worked correctly on LINUX, because SAS software is 64b there too. Maybe it had too be something with different gcc instalations over these two environments.